# How to automate calculation of standard deviation and mean of many images in a folder (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to learn how to let it continuously run to calculate every single image in a folder of standard deviation and mean of the images.

my current code is like this, it's basic manual code...

For current code is this it:

```
im = Image.open(r'path of the image')
stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
img = mahotas.imread(r'path of the image')
mean = img.mean()
print(str(mean))
print(stat.stddev)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory and use a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the entire files in the directory by `listdir` and iterate the files through `for` loop

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageStat

dir_path = "Your Directory/Image Folder/"
listOfImageFiles = os.listdir(dir_path)
fileext = ('.png', 'jpg', 'jpeg')

for imageFile in listOfImageFiles:
    if imageFile.endswith(fileext):
       im = Image.open(os.path.join(dir_path,imageFile))
       stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
       img = mahotas.imread(os.path.join(dir_path,imageFile))
       mean = img.mean()
       print(str(mean))
       print(stat.stddev)
```

Comment: `os.listdir` also returns folders, so you need to check whether `imageFile` is actually a file. Furthermore, I think, the file ending of `imageFile` should also be checked. Your solution only works if all files in `Your Directory/Image Folder/` are appropriate image files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the code is running will but if only can calculate one of the image only and it cant proceed with another images, below is the message I get...

DecompressionBombWarning: Image size (92875872 pixels) exceeds limit of 89478485 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.
  warnings.warn( 187.59779772286822 [69.11878315244641]

Comment: Green, Yes you are right. `os.walk` will be the right choice

Comment: `import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)` to ignore such warning.

Comment: If the answer helps , Please mark this as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) function is what you need. It walks the file tree recursively and returns all folder and file names within each directory. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for details. Here's how you would use it to compute the mean and standard deviation for each image file in a folder:

```
import os

IMAGE_FORMATS = {'.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'}

for root_path, _, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/your/folder'):
    for filename in filenames:
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext in IMAGE_FORMATS:
            full_path = os.path.join(root_path, filename)
            im = Image.open(full_path)
            stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
            img = mahotas.imread(full_path)
            mean = img.mean()
            print(f"Image {full_path}: mean={mean}, stddev={stat.stddev}")
```

Note: the difference of `os.walk` to `os.listdir` is that `os.walk` walks the file tree recursively, i.e., it will also walk through each sub-folder and look for images there. `os.listdir` only lists the files and directories of exactly the folder you provide, but doesn't walk through sub-folders.

Comment: Hi, for the mahotas.imread(r'path of the image') section there, as i put my path like "/Users/user/desktop/internal_triggered", i have error for it like this
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that line. It should be `mahotas.imread(full_path)`. I changed my answer accordingly.